# LinearLayout expanding when adding TextView to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

I am using android:weight attribute.

First state

http://s1.postimg.org/umygk8han/first.png

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="223"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
   </LinearLayout>
```

When add TextView

http://s7.postimg.org/89qjb42dn/two.png

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="223"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="Sample"
      android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Best regards

Comment: Share Layout code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that initially you need a `RelativeLayout` outside of the 
`LinearLayout` , because I don't think it is a good idea to 
assign layout_weight to a `LinearLayout`.

So do it like this:

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_weight="223"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>     <TextView
>        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>        android:text="Sample"
>        android:maxLines="1"
>        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" /> 
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

PS: I set the `android:layout_height="0dp"` of this `RelativeLayout` because it looked to me (according to the screenshots) that it was a node of a `LinearLayour` with `orientation='vertical'`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the linearlayout expands due to font size in the textView, try to decrease font size.

```
<TextView ....    
  android:textSize="9sp" />
```

Also you could try to set padding textview to 0

```
 android:padding="0dp"
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try setting `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in your `TextView` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Sample" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Sample" />
</LinearLayout>
```